# Next.js 13, MUI, transpilePackages and modularizeImports

Tags: next.js, material-ui, next.js13

My project is a monorepository using [Turborepo](https://turbo.build/repo) and [MUI](https://mui.com). I'm using [Next.js 13](https://nextjs.org) and would like to optimize the performance. I found an article where they use the new transpilePackages and modularizeImports properties to optimize the imports in the application (see [here](https://medium.com/@yashashr/next-js-optimization-for-better-performance-part-1-material-ui-mui-configs-plugins-6fdc48a4e984)). I don't know how to set up next.config.js (the procedure in the article doesn't work).

If I set up next.config.js according to the article. That is, I add @mui libraries to the transpilePackages parameter and then use the same parameters as in the article to modularizeImports:

```js
{
    "@mui/material/?(((\\w*)?/?)*)": {
        transform: "@mui/material/{{ matches.[1] }}/{{member}}",
    },
    "@mui/icons-material/?(((\\w*)?/?)*)": {
        transform: "@mui/icons-material/{{ matches.[1] }}/{{member}}",
    },
}
```

I get a module not found error if I import css or styled from @mui/material:

```
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...
error - ../../packages/core/icons/Icon.tsx:14:0
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/material/css'
import { css, styled } from "@mui/material";
```

I tried a lot of things and managed to get another similar bug, but with the alpha function (and some others as well). I assume the modularizeImports parameters are not correct, but I don't know how it should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add this below to your .next.config.js file :

`transpilePackages: ["@mui/material/css"]`

Sample .next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  transpilePackages: ["@mui/material/css", etc..]
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with other modules. What solved it for me:

In the next.config.js I use a similar approach to what is shown in the [MUI docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#option-two-use-a-babel-plugin)

```
  `modularizeImports: {
    '@mui/icons-material': {
      transform: '@mui/icons-material/{{member}}',
    },
    '@mui/material': {
      transform: '@mui/material/{{member}}',
    },
  },`
```

I don't import everything from top level. In your case this should fix it:

`import { css } from '@mui/material/styles';`